# $_SESSION equals value from database?

Tags: php, session-variables

when a person logs into my site i need to check a value in a database for their roleid, and dependent on that i need to allow/deny access to a page.

I have this code but it says that the $_SESION variable 'Access' is undefined, i cant see why?

```
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
            $password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));

            $checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE email = '" . $email . "' AND password2 = '" . $password . "'");

            if (mysql_num_rows($checklogin) == 1) {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($checklogin);
                $roleid = $row['roleid'];

                $_SESSION['Email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['Access'] = $roleid;

                echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
                echo "<p>We are now redirecting you to the member area.</p>";
                echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;index.php' />";
            } 

            else {
                echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
                echo "<p>Sorry, your account could not be found. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to try again</a>.</p>";
            }
        }
```

This is the if statement that is saying the session in undefined:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['Email']) && $_SESSION['Access'] == '2')
```

***EDIT***
Sorry, should have mentioned, session_start() is called in my base.php file which is included in this file.

EDIT

I don't know what the problem is, i can assign the variable $email to the other session variable and display that so the user can see who they are logged in as?

Does anybody have any suggestions? Both of the other session variables work fine.

Comment: is this session_start() called before database start up scripts?

Answer (score 7):

From the code you have posted, you are missing `session_start()`

If this is not within a framework that performs this for you, it must be called on every page that will utilize the session before any session calls are made.

I assume the error is occurring after the redirect, in your logic that is checking for it using `isset()` or `empty()`.  Add `session_start()` to both pages before any session logic is performed.

**EDIT**:

Ok, you have `session_start()`.  Can you `print_r()` your `$_SESSION` and check the output?

Also, the file you mention that runs the session start should be included in both files, as its necessary for setting and checking values from the session.

Make sure before running any `empty()` conditionals, you also run `isset()`.  Empty does not check if the key is present.

**EDIT AGAIN**:

Is it possible your value for `$y` isn't coming out of the database as a single value?  can you `die()` at that point, just printing the value of `$y` out to see what is output?

Comment: And you are certain that the session is being initialized on both pages?  That call should print something out from the array if the session is initialized.  The only other thing I could think of would be config issues, but I doubt that's the problem.  Can you post the complete scripts either in your question or on https://gist.github.com/ ?

Comment: I put this outside the while loop: echo $y;die(); But it didn't do anything.

Comment: @user667430 $y must be empty for some reason.  We have found your problem.  Something within this call stack does not set that value.  You'll forgive me cause I don't use the core mysql funcs for my queries and use PDO instead, so I'm not totally familiar with the structure of the returns.  Can you run `print_r($row)` right where you put the echo before die and let me know what that does?  It should show us exactly what's coming out of the DB.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. i have put print_r($row) were the echo was after the while statement but nothing happened. You'll have to excuse me im not very good with PHP

Answer (score 0):

Just add another check to your if statement, `!empty($_SESSION['Access'])`

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) 
   && !empty($_SESSION['Email']) 
   && !empty($_SESSION['Access']) 
   && $_SESSION['Access'] == '2')
```

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work, the problem is that the session variable is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of $row['roleid'].  Is the field name in the database table EXACTLY like it ?

Change

SELECT * FROM person WHERE

to

SELECT roleid FROM person WHERE

see if it breaks... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related to your problem but I think it's worth mentioning: Your username / password SQL statement can be dangerous. Although you escape the input variables it is usually better practice to do it this way:

```
$checklogin = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE email='".$email."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array ($checklogin, MYSQL_ASSOC);

if (mysql_num_rows ($checklogin) == 1 && $row['password'] == $password)
{
 // you are logged in
}
else
{
 // wrong email or password
}
```

Reason being is that your current statement only needs to return ANY row in your table whereas this statement needs to return one specific row in the table.